# DetailView update is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have googled every where but without a clear answer
I am trying to update a record using Detail view using the following code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="2" DataKeyNames="Rec_ID" DataSourceID="ContactsMasterDS" 
        ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" PageSize="3">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Full_Name" HeaderText="Full_Name" SortExpression="Full_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AgeGroup" HeaderText="AgeGroup" SortExpression="AgeGroup" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nationality" HeaderText="Nationality" SortExpression="Nationality" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Occupation" HeaderText="Occupation" SortExpression="Occupation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Resident" HeaderText="Resident" SortExpression="Resident" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ContactsMasterDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="Select * from Contacts"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Rec_ID" DataSourceID="ContactsDetailsDS" Height="50px" 
        Width="545px" onitemupdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Rec_ID" HeaderText="Rec_ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Rec_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AgeGroup" HeaderText="AgeGroup" SortExpression="AgeGroup" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Full_Name" HeaderText="Full_Name" SortExpression="Full_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone_No" HeaderText="Phone_No" SortExpression="Phone_No" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nationality" HeaderText="Nationality" SortExpression="Nationality" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Account_No" HeaderText="Account_No" SortExpression="Account_No" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Occupation" HeaderText="Occupation" SortExpression="Occupation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Resident" HeaderText="Resident" SortExpression="Resident" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Room_No" HeaderText="Room_No" SortExpression="Room_No" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Branch" HeaderText="Last_Branch" SortExpression="Last_Branch" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Date" HeaderText="Last_Date" SortExpression="Last_Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Time" HeaderText="Last_Time" SortExpression="Last_Time" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="isComplete" HeaderText="isComplete" SortExpression="isComplete" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ContactsDetailsDS" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="Select * from Contacts where [Rec_ID] = @Rec_ID" 
        UpdateCommand="Update Contacts Set Room_No=@Room_No Where Rec_ID=@Rec_ID" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Rec_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Room_No" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rec_ID" Type="String" DefaultValue="0" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

when I change the where clause to be "Where Rec_ID = 2" it works, but when using parameter it does not do the required update
any help please

Comment: Try changing this: <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" to
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1"

Comment: try this. make your Rec_Id a label instead of a textbox. I ran into this a few weeks ago and that worked. and 
convert(varchar, rec_id) LIKE @rec_id.

Comment: It is a read only field , so it is a label, should i change that ?

Comment: did you change your sql statement to where convert(varchar, Rec_Id) LIKE @Rec_Id

Comment: If I remove the read only from the Rec_ID , it will work, other wise it wont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as follows:

1- in the where clause: Change the Rec_ID into any other name like ID for example.

before: `UpdateCommand="Update Contacts Set Room_No=@Room_No Where [Rec_ID]=@Rec_ID">`

after : `UpdateCommand="Update Contacts Set Room_No=@Room_No Where [Rec_ID]=@ID">`

2- in the UpdateParameters get the value of ID as such:

before: `<asp:Parameter Name="Rec_ID" Type="Int32" />`

after: `<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DetailsView1" Name="ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />`

this will allow you to keep the Rec_ID as read only or even remove hide it from the DetailsView

Thanks for all of you

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void OnDetailsViewItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e) {
        if (String.Equals((string)e.NewValues["firstName"], "john", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            // "John" is not a valid name, so change it to "Steve":
            e.NewValues["firstName"] = "Steve";
        }
        if (String.Equals((string)e.NewValues["lastName"], "doe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            // If "Doe" is the last name, cancel the whole operation
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

}
```

You have to write "OnItemUpdated" not onitemupdated. Check case.

Hope this helps you.
The DetailsView control's ItemUpdating event has arguments that contain both the original data (if available) as well as the new data that the user typed in. Here's an example of how to check the data and optionally modify it

Comment: So we have to use code behind to do the update, microsoft examples on detail view do not use any , they just relay on the asp control to do the job